# VS Code formatando erroneamente arquivos .ejs ao salvar

Tags: visual-studio-code

Gostaria de saber como configuro o vs code para não formatar arquivos automaticamente ao salvar. Isso acontece muito em arquivos .ejs e é muito chato. Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.

Comment: Nenhuma das três o vs code não coloca mais settings.json, é so pela interface.

Comment: atualizei a resposta de como abrir o settings.json

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + shift + p, vai abrir uma janela, coloca o settings.json

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desabilita nas configurações do **vscode.** `FormatOnSave`.

ou

Insere esse item no seu `settings.json` `"editor.formatOnSave": false,`

ou

Se quiser não formatar só uma determinada extensão do arquivo:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true 
"[jade]": { "editor.formatOnSave": false }
```

Comment: Por algum motivo isso não funciona.

Comment: a minha ja esta desabilitada e não funciona

Comment: Qual deles vcs tentaram? Eu dei três opções.